# ASP.NET MVC Having trouble understanding routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I've got this group project that I'm trying to understand and have problems with how the routes work in it. The first thing that bothers me is why are there some routes registered in the RouteConfig.cs file and other in the Global.asax? Why is routes.Add used in RouteConfig.cs and what does it do in comparison to routes.MapRoute?

Here's RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Add(new LowercaseDashedRoute("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
                new DashedRouteHandler()
            )
        );

    }
```

Here's Global.asax:

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute("SpecificRouteforHomeController", "{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });

        // default route  any defalt you want
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Services", action = "Index", id = "" });
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are not calling `RegisterRoutes` in the Global.asax anywhere. Are you ?

Comment: It sure looks like it. Where else could it be called from?